# Kommasetzung bei Mischung aus Nebensatz und Präposition

Tags: comma

Wie setzt man in solchen Fällen Kommata, bei denen Gleichartiges einmal als Nebensatz und einmal mit einer Präposition formuliert wird?

Beispiele:

> Bei Regen oder wenn es schneit bleibe ich zu Hause
>
> Wegen der netten Bedienung und weil das Essen schmeckt ist dies mein Lieblingsrestaurant
>
> Trotz des hohen Preises und obwohl ich schon ein Auto habe musste ich unbedingt den Porsche kaufen

Ganz ohne Komma sieht das ganz falsch aus, aber wenn man am Ende des Nebensatzes ein Komma setzt, müsste man meines Erachtens auch vorne eins setzen – aber sowohl „Bei Regen oder, wenn …“ als auch „Bei Regen, oder wenn …“ fühlen sich meines Erachtens falsch an.

Und das geht natürlich auch in umgekehrter Reihenfolge:

> Wenn es schneit oder bei Regen bleibe ich zu Hause
>
> Weil das Essen schmeckt und wegen der netten Bedienung ist dies mein Lieblingsrestaurant
>
> Obwohl ich schon ein Auto habe und trotz des hohen Preises musste ich unbedingt den Porsche kaufen

Answer (score 4):

Laut Duden Band 9 – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* handelt es sich hierbei um Aufzählungen von Satzteilen.

Dabei steht **kein** Komma vor *und* oder *oder,* wenn diese Konjunktionen in einer Aufzählung Satzglieder oder Satzgliedteile mit Nebensätzen verbinden:

> Sie kaufte sich einen Koffer, einen Mantel, ein Kleid und was sie sonst noch für die Reise brauchte.
>
> Außerordentlich bedauert hat er diesen Vorfall und dass er nichts dagegen tun konnte.
>
> Das Rauchen ist hier verboten bei großer Dürre oder wenn der Föhn weht.
>
> Wenn der Föhn weht oder bei großer Dürre ist das Rauchen hier verboten.

Die Teile der Aufzählung werden nur dann durch ein Komma voneinander abgegrenzt, wenn Haupt- und Nebensatz unmittelbar aufeinanderfolgen:

> Das Rauchen ist hier verboten, wenn der Föhn weht oder bei großer Dürre.
>
> Bei großer Dürre oder wenn der Föhn weht, ist das Rauchen hier verboten.

Fast gleiche Beispiele findet man in der Erläuterung E2 zu der amtlichen Regel § 74:

> E2: Wenn eine beiordnende Konjunktion wie *und, oder* (§ 72) Satzglieder oder Teile von Satzgliedern mit Nebensätzen verbindet, so steht zwischen den Bestandteilen einer solchen Reihung kein Komma. Gegenüber dem übergeordneten Satz sind die Teile der Reihung nur dann mit Komma abgetrennt, wenn der Nebensatz anschließt, nicht aber, wenn das Satzglied
>   bzw. ein Teil eines Satzgliedes anschließt
>
> *Außerordentlich bedauert hat er diesen Vorfall und dass das hier geschehen
>   konnte.*
>
> *Bei großer Dürre oder wenn der Föhn weht, ist das Rauchen hier streng verboten.*
>
> *Wenn der Föhn weht oder bei großer Dürre ist das Rauchen hier streng verboten.*
>
> *Das Rauchen ist hier streng verboten bei großer Dürre oder wenn der Föhn weht.*
>
> *Das Rauchen ist hier streng verboten, wenn der Föhn weht oder bei großer Dürre.*

Answer (score 1):

Ich denke, im Schriftlichen sollte man solche gemischten Begründungen besser vermeiden, eben weil sie grammatikalisch verschieden sind. *Bei Regen bleibe ich zu Hause* und *Wenn es schneit, bleibe ich zu Hause* sind jedes für sich korrekte Formulierungen, aber in der Kombination wirkt es irgendwie wie zwei Puzzleteile, die zusammengesteckt wurden, aber nicht wirklich zusammenpassen. Es klingt wie gesprochene Sprache, bei der ein Satz begonnen und erst "unterwegs" zuende formuliert wurde. Beim Schreiben, wenn man nicht unter Zeitdruck steht, kann (und sollte) man sorgfältiger formulieren. Wenn es aus irgend einem Grund unvermeidlich ist, würde ich die Kommata so setzen:

> Bei Regen, oder wenn es schneit, bleibe ich zu Hause.

Analog auch die anderen Beispielsätze, aber wie gesagt würde ich mir schriftlich Mühe geben, eine alternative Aufzählung mit zweimal der gleichen grammatikalischen Form zu finden.

Comment: Mit anderen Worten: *Beim Schreiben und wenn man nicht unter Zeitdruck steht, [?] sollte man sorgfältiger formulieren.* - Scherz beiseite: Du hast zwar recht, aber es kann trotzdem Situationen geben, wo man dem Problem nicht ausweichen kann: beim wörtlichen Transkribieren mündlicher Rede zum Beispiel. Das betrifft zwar nicht so viele Menschen (denn nur wenige Menschen transkribieren regelmäßig mündliche Sprachäußerungen), aber die, die es betrifft, betrifft es um so häufiger.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Mein Satz enthielt aber **kein** *und*, weil es eben keine Aufzählung ist. Da mein Arm nicht von hier bis zu Deinem Wohnort reicht, wirst Du Dir den Klaps, den Du für Deinen Scherz verdienst, wohl selber geben müssen :-P -- Zum Punkt *Transkribieren*: das fällt dann in die Rubrik *Wenn es aus irgend einem Grund unvermeidlich ist*.